# Inner join to get those not in table

Tags: .net, database, linq, entity-framework

I have two tables in my database. A person and a coach table. The person table contains all the people and if one of the people is a coach his ID will be in the coach table.
I need to find all the people who are not coaches... yet and post them in a list.
I have tried:

```
var query = from es in gr.people
                            join esh in gr.coaches on es.id equals esh.personID
                            where es.id != esh.personID
                            select es;
```

And this:

```
var query = from es in gr.people
                            join esh in gr.coaches on es.id equals esh.personID
                            where es.id != esh.personID && es.id.hasValue
                            select es;
```

But the last one doesn't alow the .hasValue. And so far it doesn't work :(
Can anybody help me or give me a hint??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try:

```
var result = gr.people.Where(p => !gr.coaches.Any(c => c.personID == p.id));
```

Comment: I used this for a workaround when trying to join a list of linq-to-sql objects with a linq-to-sql table (which the compiler will block b/c the types are not equivalent). Nice move!